# How to save QR code string/information into firebase and toast it into list view (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, qr-code

I am doing attendant QR code scanner program. I manage to make the QR scanner by following YouTube tutorial. But now I am wondering, how can I save the attendant information that been created into QR code and save it into firebase or array and passing the information into list view.[The example of the list view with the QR code attendant information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvNaQ.png)

Comment: Does [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data?hl=en) help you?

Comment: Here you might find a related [questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233434/how-to-get-the-string-value-of-qr-code-and-store-it-into-firebase-so-it-links-to)